# Не стилизуется блок в макете

Tags: css3

Верстаю макет. Все было хорошо, пока не споткнулся на одном блоке, который не хочет стилизоваться. Проблемные места выделил комментариями "отсюда", "до сюда".

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Georgia', sans-serif;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 0 22px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
  min-height: 52px;
  background-color: #2d2928;
}

.header .header__inside {
  padding: 8px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: center;
}

.header .header__inside nav li,
.main .navigation nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.header .header__inside nav a {
  color: #c4c4c4;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.header .header__inside nav a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

.header .header__inside .circles .circle {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.main .headline {
  min-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main .headline h1 {
  font-size: 100px;
  line-height: 150px;
  color: #282828;
}

.main .headline p {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #4a4a4a;
}

.main .line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #999999;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}

.main .navigation nav li {
  margin: 1% 4% 1% 0;
}

.main .navigation nav li a {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  color: #333333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main .navigation nav li a:hover {
  color: #999999;
}

.main .main__news__inside {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 30px;
  padding: 40px 0;
  min-height: 541px;
}

.main .main__news__inside .main__left {
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  display: grid;
}

.main .main__news__inside .main__left .main__left__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333333;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.main .main__news__inside .main__left .main__left__article {
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  align-self: center;
}

.main .main__news__inside .main__left .main__left__img p {
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 350px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.main .main__news__inside h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #444444;
  margin-bottom: 1.5%;
}

.main .main__news__inside p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 19px;
  color: #666666;
}

.main .main__news__inside .main__right {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: center;
}

.main .border {
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main .main__news__inside .main__right .main__right__img {
  width: 97%;
  height: 94.5%;
  background-color: #333333;
  margin: 3px;
}

.main .main__news__inside .main__right .main__right__img p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: #fff;
}

.main .main__news__inside .main__right .main__right__article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-gap: 17px;
}

.main .main__news__inside .main__right .main__right__article .smth {
  align-self: center;
}

.main .main__news__inside .main__right .main__right__article:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
}

.main .secondary {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 30px;
  padding-top: 34px;
}

.main .secondary .secondary__first .line {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.main .secondary .secondary__left {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.main .secondary .secondary__left .secondary__first {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
}

.main .secondary .secondary__left .secondary__first .secondary__article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-gap: 9px;
}

.main .secondary .secondary__left .secondary__first .secondary__article .smth {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.main .secondary .secondary__left .secondary__first .secondary__article .smth a {
  align-self: end;
}

.main .secondary .secondary__left .secondary__first .secondary__articles {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.main .secondary .secondary__left .secondary__first .secondary__articles .border p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 56px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.main .secondary .secondary__left .secondary__first .secondary__article .secondary__first__left__img {
  width: 95%;
  height: 91.5%;
  background-color: #333333;
  margin: 3px;
}

.main .secondary .secondary__left .secondary__first .secondary__articles h4 {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
  color: #444444;
}

.main .secondary .secondary__left .secondary__first .secondary__articles p {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
  color: #666666;
}

.main .secondary .secondary__left .secondary__first .secondary__articles a {
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 11px;
  color: #982115;
  text-align: right;
  display: block;
}

/* Отсюда   */

.main .secondary .secondary__left .secondary__second .secondary__second__articles {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 26px;
}

.main .secondary .secondary__left .secondary__second .secondary__second__articles .secondary__article {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

/* До сюда */

.main .secondary .secondary__right {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.main .secondary .secondary__right .third__nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.main .secondary .secondary__right .third__nav a {
  color: #982115;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 21px;
}

.main .secondary .secondary__right h4 {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 13px;
  color: #666666;
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}

.main .secondary .secondary__right .bold__line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #999999;
  margin: 15px 0 10px;
}

.main .secondary .secondary__right .advertisement .secondary__third__img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: #333333;
}

.main .secondary .secondary__right .advertisement .secondary__third__img p {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css">
    <title>psd_9</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>


      <div class="header container">
        <div class="header__inside">
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sign Up |</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Login |</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">RSS Feeds |</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Archived News</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <div class="circles">
            <div class="circle"></div>
            <div class="circle"></div>
            <div class="circle"></div>
            <div class="circle"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="main container">
        <div class="headline">
          <h1>MAG MAGAZINE</h1>
          <p>ALL THE LATEST NEWS & INFORMATION IN THE WORLD</p>
        </div>
        <div class="navigation">
          <div class="double__line">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
          </div>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">homepage</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">style demo</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">full width</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">link text</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <div class="double__line">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main__news">
          <div class="main__news__inside">

            <div class="main__left">
              <div class="main__left__img">
                <p>500 x 320px</p>
              </div>
              <div class="main__left__article">
                <h3>Cursus penati saccum ut curabitur nulla.</h3>
                <p>maurisque eros molest nunc anteget sed vel lacus mus semper. Anterdumnullam interdum eros dui urna consequam ac nisl nullam ligula vestassa. Condimentumfelis et amet tellent quisquet a leo lacus nec augue accumsan. Sagittislaorem dolor
                  sum at urna et pharetium malesuada nis cons ectus.</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="main__right">
              <div class="main__right__article">
                <div class="border">
                  <div class="main__right__img">
                    <p>100 x 100px</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="smth">
                  <h3>Cursus penati saccum curabi</h3>
                  <p>Cursuspenatisaccum ut curabitur nulla tellus tor ames a in curabitur pede. Idet mollisi eros dis orci congue elis et curabitur.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="main__right__article">
                <h3>Cursus penati saccum ut curabitur nulla.</h3>
                <p>Cursuspenatisaccum ut curabitur nulla tellus tor ames a in curabitur pede. Idet mollisi eros dis orci congue elis et curabitur consequam intesque. Curabiturpisametur in ante.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="main__right__article">
                <div class="border">
                  <div class="main__right__img">
                    <p>100 x 100px</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="smth">
                  <h3>Cursus penati saccum curabi</h3>
                  <p>Cursuspenatisaccum ut curabitur nulla tellus tor ames a in curabitur pede. Idet mollisi eros dis orci congue elis et curabitur.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="main__right__article">
                <div class="border">
                  <div class="main__right__img">
                    <p>100 x 100px</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="smth">
                  <h3>Cursus penati saccum curabi</h3>
                  <p>Cursuspenatisaccum ut curabitur nulla tellus tor ames a in curabitur pede. Idet mollisi eros dis orci congue elis et curabitur.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="double__line">
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="secondary">
          <div class="secondary__left">
            <div class="secondary__first">
              <div class="secondary__first__left">
                <h3>LOREM IPSUM</h3>
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="secondary__articles">
                  <div class="secondary__article">
                    <div class="border">
                      <div class="secondary__first__left__img">
                        <p>60x60px</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="smth">
                      <h4>Indonectetus facilis</h4>
                      <p>maurisque eros molest nunc anteget sed vel lacus mus semper. Anterd umnullam interdum eros dui urna</p>
                      <a href="#">READ MORE »</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="secondary__article">
                    <div class="border">
                      <div class="secondary__first__left__img">
                        <p>60x60px</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="smth">
                      <h4>Indonectetus facilis</h4>
                      <p>maurisque eros molest nunc anteget sed vel lacus mus semper. Anterd umnullam interdum eros dui urna</p>
                      <a href="#">READ MORE »</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="secondary__article">
                    <div class="border">
                      <div class="secondary__first__left__img">
                        <p>60x60px</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="smth">
                      <h4>Indonectetus facilis</h4>
                      <p>maurisque eros molest nunc anteget sed vel lacus mus semper. Anterd umnullam interdum eros dui urna</p>
                      <a href="#">READ MORE »</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="secondary__first__right">
                <h3>LOREM IPSUM</h3>
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="secondary__articles">
                  <div class="secondary__article">
                    <div class="border">
                      <div class="secondary__first__left__img">
                        <p>60x60px</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="smth">
                      <h4>Indonectetus facilis</h4>
                      <p>maurisque eros molest nunc anteget sed vel lacus mus semper. Anterd umnullam interdum eros dui urna</p>
                      <a href="#">READ MORE »</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="secondary__article">
                    <div class="border">
                      <div class="secondary__first__left__img">
                        <p>60x60px</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="smth">
                      <h4>Indonectetus facilis</h4>
                      <p>maurisque eros molest nunc anteget sed vel lacus mus semper. Anterd umnullam interdum eros dui urna</p>
                      <a href="#">READ MORE »</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="secondary__article">
                    <div class="border">
                      <div class="secondary__first__left__img">
                        <p>60x60px</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="smth">
                      <h4>Indonectetus facilis</h4>
                      <p>maurisque eros molest nunc anteget sed vel lacus mus semper. Anterd umnullam interdum eros dui urna</p>
                      <a href="#">READ MORE »</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Вот этот блок. Отсюда -->
            <div class="secandary__second">
              <div class="double__line">
                <div class="line"></div>
                <div class="line"></div>
              </div>
              <nav>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">FINANCIAL WORLD</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">SPORTS WORLD</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">PROMI WORLD</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">MUSIC & ARTS WORLD</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>

              <!-- А точнее отсюда -->
              <div class="secondary__second__articles">
                <div class="secondary__second__article">
                  <h4><a href="#"></a>Sed vel lacus mus semper.</h4>
                  <div class="border">
                    <div class="secondary__img">
                      <p>122 x 80px</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <p>Maurisque eros molest nunc anteget sed vel lacus mus semper. Anterd umnullam interdum eros duiur.</p>
                  <p>Tag: <a href="#">Tag Name »</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="secondary__second__article">
                  <h4><a href="#"></a>Sed vel lacus mus semper.</h4>
                  <div class="border">
                    <div class="secondary__img">
                      <p>122 x 80px</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <p>Maurisque eros molest nunc anteget sed vel lacus mus semper. Anterd umnullam interdum eros duiur.</p>
                  <p>Tag: <a href="#">Tag Name »</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="secondary__second__article">
                  <h4><a href="#"></a>Sed vel lacus mus semper.</h4>
                  <div class="border">
                    <div class="secondary__img">
                      <p>122 x 80px</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <p>Maurisque eros molest nunc anteget sed vel lacus mus semper. Anterd umnullam interdum eros duiur.</p>
                  <p>Tag: <a href="#">Tag Name »</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="secondary__second__article">
                  <h4><a href="#"></a>Sed vel lacus mus semper.</h4>
                  <div class="border">
                    <div class="secondary__img">
                      <p>122 x 80px</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <p>Maurisque eros molest nunc anteget sed vel lacus mus semper. Anterd umnullam interdum eros duiur.</p>
                  <p>Tag: <a href="#">Tag Name »</a></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- До сюда -->
            </div>
            <!-- До сюда -->
          </div>
          <div class="secondary__right">
            <div class="advertisement">
              <div class="bold__line"></div>
              <h4>Advertisement</h4>
              <div class="secondary__third__img">
                <p>160 x 600px</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="third__nav">
              <div class="third__categories">
                <div class="bold__line"></div>
                <h4>Categories</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">» Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">» Suspendisse in neque</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">» Praesent et eros</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">» Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">» Suspendisse in neque</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">» Praesent et eros</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">» Praesent et eros</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">» Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">» Suspendisse in neque</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="third__link__header__1">
                <div class="bold__line"></div>
                <h4>Link Header</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">» Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">» Suspendisse in neque</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">» Praesent et eros</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">» Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">» Suspendisse in neque</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">» Praesent et eros</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">» Praesent et eros</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">» Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">» Suspendisse in neque</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="third__link__header__2">
                <div class="bold__line"></div>
                <h4>Link Header</h4>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">» Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">» Suspendisse in neque</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">» Praesent et eros</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">» Lorem ipsum dolor</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">» Suspendisse in neque</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">» Praesent et eros</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>

</html>
```

[Папка с проектом на гитхабе](https://github.com/oximon/problem)

[Код на jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nbje2hg1/)

Comment: Сделайте тут снипет который сможет воспроизвести вашу проблему, либо используйте сервисы codepen\jsfiddle

Comment: То, что не стилизовано, никак не поддается. https://jsfiddle.net/nbje2hg1/